# Why does ffmpeg4android fail on Galaxy S6?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-codecs

I have created an app that uses the ffmpeg4android library found here:
http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

I succesfully managed to encode & crop video using the following command:
"ffmpeg -y -i [input_video_path] -preset ultrafast -strict -2 -vf crop=480:480:[startX]:0 -r 25 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k [outputPath]"

This command works on several devices: motorola G (api 22), galaxy s4 being some of them.

Yet, on galaxy S6 it crashes when executing the command.
In the ffmpeg log, it says that it does not recognize the preset option. Can anyone help me understand why and what is the proper fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the response at the source:

"Solution 1:
Use mpeg4 encoder (-vcodec mpeg4) and remove the  -preset ultrafast.

Solution 2:
Remove the arm64-v8a folder from the ffmpeg4android_lib﻿"